# How do glitter gift package sheets work?

Tags: visible-light, waves, reflection

You must have seen gift package sheets. When I see it from one angle it gives different color of light , when I see same point at another angle it gives different color of light. How ? If substance is same..how can perspective change color of light.

Answer (score 0):

the glitter wrap has a plastic surface which has been embossed with a series of extremely fine and uniformly spaced parallel scratches to form something called a diffraction grating, which causes a beam of white light striking it to be separated into its constituent colors upon reflection. Lots of information on how a diffraction grating works and how they are made can be found on-line.